# running a function in parallel in Python

Tags: python, loops, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run a function like `f` in parallel in Python but have two problems:

1. When using `map`, function `f` is not applied to all permuted tuples of arrays `a` and `b`.
2. When trying to use `Pool`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

```
def f(n,m):
    x = n * m
    return x

a = (1,2,3,4,5)
b = (3,4,7,8,9)
result = map(f, a, b)
print(list(result))

#now trying parallel computing
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=4)
print(*pool.map(f, a, b))
```

Comment: "function f is not applied to all permuted tuples of arrays a and b." Why do you think it should be? What does the `map` documentation say? Exactly which function calls do you want to be made for this input, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't make any changes for your #1 issue and get the expected result from using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map).  You seem to have an incorrect assumption of how it works, but didn't provide expectation vs. actual results for your example.

for #2 to return the same answers as #1, you need [`starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) instead of [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) for this instance of [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) use, and then [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the argument lists to provide sets of arguments.  If on an OS that doesn't `fork` (and for portability if you are), run global code only if it is the main process, and not a spawned process by using the [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods) `if __name__ == '__main__':` idiom:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(n,m):
    x = n * m
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = (1,2,3,4,5)
    b = (3,4,7,8,9)
    result = map(f, a, b)
    print(list(result))

    #now trying parallel computing
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    print(*pool.starmap(f, zip(a, b)))
```

Output:

```
[3, 8, 21, 32, 45]
3 8 21 32 45
```

If you actually want permutations as mentioned in #1, use `itertools.starmap` or `pool.starmap` with `itertools.product(a,b)` as parameters instead.